# Am I okay to keep using the old version of flutter packages

Tags: flutter

Hi I have a question about usage of old flutter packages. I am trying to build a push notification app using Firebase but I am finding very difficulties due to lack of information. I know there are some tutorials that teaches how to use the latest FCM package in flutter but still not very clear for me but I can find a lot of information that works in prior versions. So I am thinking to start using the prior version of FCM to implement push notification and once I find good resources then give it a go but I just want to know what are the risks of using old version of packages?

Comment: Using old version of any plugin simply means that you may have lack of functionalities and features but if you are okay with it then you can use.

Comment: My opinion is if you are trying to learn something new, it's best to learn the latest version available at the moment. So you don't have to relearn when it's time to upgrade.

Comment: I made that mistake earlier, I would not do it if I were you. Stick with the newest version.